# Parsing an RSS feed cuts of characters

Tags: android, parsing, rss, character

I parse some RSS feed (tried with different ones...) and everytime pretty randomly characters get cut of.
What am I doing wrong? Why does it work in some instances and in other ones it doesn't?
Is there another way of doing it? The XML will (in most of the cases) include UTF-8 characters (like ä,ö,ü etc.) so the solution should work with those characters too.

If you need any more information (More code, more detailed information etc.) please let me know!

Here is my Code:

```
public class RSSHandler extends DefaultHandler {

final int state_unknown = 0;
final int state_title = 1;
final int state_description = 2;
final int state_link = 3;
final int state_pubdate = 4;
int currentState = state_unknown;
StringBuilder strCharacters;

RSSFeed feed;
RSSItem item;

boolean inEntity = false;
String entityName = "";

boolean itemFound = false;

public RSSHandler() {
    strCharacters = new StringBuilder();
}

public RSSFeed getFeed() {
    return feed;
}

@Override
public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
    feed = new RSSFeed();
    item = new RSSItem();
}

@Override
public void endDocument() throws SAXException {
}

@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    strCharacters = new StringBuilder();
    if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
        itemFound = true;
        item = new RSSItem();
        currentState = state_unknown;
    } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
        currentState = state_title;
    } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("description")) {
        currentState = state_description;
    } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("link")) {
        currentState = state_link;
    } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("pubdate")) {
        currentState = state_pubdate;
    } else {
        currentState = state_unknown;
    }

}

@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
        throws SAXException {
    if (itemFound == true) {
        switch (currentState) {
            case state_title:
                item.setTitle(strCharacters.toString());
                break;
            case state_description:
                break;
            case state_link:
                item.setLink(strCharacters.toString());
                break;
            case state_pubdate:
                String dateStr = strCharacters.toString();
                SimpleDateFormat curFormater = new SimpleDateFormat(
                        "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.ENGLISH);
                Date dateObj = null;
                try {
                    dateObj = curFormater.parse(dateStr);
                    SimpleDateFormat postFormater = new SimpleDateFormat(
                            "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm");
                    String newDateStr = postFormater.format(dateObj);
                    item.setPubdate(newDateStr);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    } else {
        switch (currentState) {
            case state_title:
                feed.setTitle(strCharacters.toString());
                break;
            case state_description:
                break;
            case state_link:
                feed.setLink(strCharacters.toString());
                break;
            case state_pubdate:
                feed.setPubdate(strCharacters.toString());
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    currentState = state_unknown;

    if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
        feed.addItem(item);
    }
}

public void startEntity(String name) throws SAXException {
    inEntity = true;
    entityName = name;
}

@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
        throws SAXException {

    strCharacters = new StringBuilder();
    if (inEntity) {
        inEntity = false;
        strCharacters.append("&" + entityName + ";");
    } else {
        for (int i = start; i < start + length; i++) {
            strCharacters.append(ch[i]);
        }
    }

    // strCharacters.append(ch, start, length);
}
```

}

Comment: It's hard to find what you are doing wrong, but one thing I can suggest to you is use [XmlPullParser](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html)

Comment: Ok thanks. Is there any good tutorial on the XmlPullParser somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a new `StringBuilder` on each `characters()` call. This is incorrect. There many be several calls to `characters()` per element -- you need to concatenate all those results, not just collect the last piece.

Comment: So how exactly would I do that?

Comment: @user754730: Create your `StringBuilder` in `startElement()`, append to it in `characters()`, and use the results in `endElement()`.

Comment: Great thanks alot! That totally did the trick (I had new StringBuilder() twice and not in startElement() only...)